# how to remove the previous values on the pageblocktable

Tags: visualforce

the pageblock table values depends on the value of the picklist. but whenever i change the value of the picklist, the previous data on the pageblock table is still there. Thanks in advance.

### controller

```
public void fetchTeacherInfo(){
       system.debug('----selectedSId-----'+selectedSId);
            for (student__c stud : [Select Id, name, first_name__c, parent__c, teacher_set__c from student__c WHERE Id = : selectedSId]){      
                teacherSet = stud.teacher_set__c;
                      }
         for (teacher__c myTeacher : [Select Id, name, first_name__c, teacher_set__c, middle_name__c from teacher__c WHERE teacher_set__c = : teacherSet]){
                myTea.add(myTeacher.id);                 
     }
     wrapTS = new List<WrapperClass>();
     for(teacher__c t : [select id, name, first_name__c, teacher_set__c,Subject__c , room_assignment__c from teacher__c  where Id = : myTea]){
           system.debug('------myTea-----'+myTea);
            wrapTS.add(new WrapperClass(t));
       }

      }
```

### VFP

```
<apex:page controller="PTCSchedulerCX"  sidebar="false" showHeader="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <!--<style>
.datelabel{
float: right;
margin-right: 200px; 
}
</style>-->
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>PTC Scheduler</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>

        <body>

            <apex:form >
                <div class="container">
                    <apex:pageBlock >



                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </div> 
            </apex:form>

            <apex:form >
                <div class="container">

                    <apex:pageBlock >
                        <div>         
                            <apex:outputLabel style="margin-left: 55px;">DELGADO, PAULO</apex:outputLabel>
                            <apex:outputLabel style="float: right; margin-right: 100px;" value="{!day}" ></apex:outputLabel>
                        </div>      

                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </div>
            </apex:form>

            <apex:form >
                <div class="container">
                    <apex:pageBlock >            
                        <div>    
                       <!--     <apex:outputText value="{!strStatus}" id="tstatus"></apex:outputText> --> 
                            <apex:outputLabel style="margin-left: 55px;">Select Student:</apex:outputLabel>

                            <apex:selectList size="1" style="margin-left: 5px;" value="{!selectedSId}">

                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!SNames}"></apex:selectOptions>

                                //<apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!fetchTeacherInfo}" reRender="teacherBlock"/>
                                <!--<apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="teacherBlock" action="{!fetchTeacherInfo}" />-->
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </div>                 
                    </apex:pageBlock>            
                </div> 

                <div class="container">                
                    <apex:pageBlock >    
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 45px;"> 
                            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!WrapTS}" var="item" id="teacherBlock">
                                <apex:column headerValue="Teacher" value="{!item.t1.First_Name__c} {!item.t1.Name}"/>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!item.t1.Subject__c}"/>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Room" value="{!item.t1.Room_Assignment__c}"/>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Time">
                                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="">
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue=""></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="9AM-10AM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="10AM-11AM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="11AM-12PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="12PM-1PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="1PM-2PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="2PM-3PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="3PM-4PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="4PM-5PM"></apex:selectOption> 
                                    </apex:selectList>
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column >
                                    <!--<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!item.check}"/>-->
                                </apex:column>
                            </apex:pageBlockTable>
                        </div>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </div>
            </apex:form>            

            <apex:form >         
                <div class="container" align="right"> 
                    <apex:pageBlock >    
                        <div style="margin-right: 50px;">       
                            <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="Proceed to Next Student"/>
                            <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="Proceed"/>
                        </div>
                    </apex:pageBlock>       
                </div>
            </apex:form>         
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        </body> 

    </html>     
</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you put the code of vf page/ class on the picklist/pageblocktable part? I think I can help

Comment: Rerender the table?

Comment: @MiczDomz updated the question please check the code

Comment: @cricketlang please see the code i have reRendered the 'teacherblock'

Comment: Are you clearing your WrapTS list before adding the new values to it in the controller?

Comment: @gelay try using the format of my sample code below

Comment: @MiczDomz please see my another question.. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for selectlist: //something like this

```
                <apex:actionRegion >      
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!ObjectNames}"/>
                        <apex:actionSupport action="{!clrList}" event="onchange" rerender="myTableId"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
            </apex:actionRegion>
```

for class: //something

```
public void fetchTeacherInfo(){
    myTea.clear();
    wrapTS .clear();
    //rest of your code
}
```

Comment: tried it. still has the previous values

Comment: myTea.clear();
    wrapTS .clear(); works! thank you ! @Micz Domz